# is there a way to exit a function when another one is called in wxpython?

Tags: function, wxpython, exit

I have two functions and when I call the second one after the first, the two functions run at the same time . I want to exit a function when another is running.
I call each function from a menuitem. I am looking for a method to terminate OnInput function when OnReadonly is called because both inputbox and readonly box are shown on the screen.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Simple App')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)        

        def OnInput(event):

            #static text
            text = wx.StaticText(panel, label ="Type your text", pos =(50, 100))

            #input text
            type = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (50, 150))

        def OnReadonly(event):

            #static text
            text = wx.StaticText(panel, label ="Status", pos =(50, 100))

            #input text
            input = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (50, 150), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|

wx.TE_READONLY)
            input.SetValue("Waiting for your file")

        menu = wx.Menu()
        it = menu.Append(-1, "Input Text")
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        rt = menu.Append(-1, "Readonly Text")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnInput, it)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnReadonly, rt)
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(menu, "Simple Menu")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Arguably, these separate functions, should be different classes i.e. new wx.frames. This would allow them to be destroyed, minimised, stay on the screen separately or be closed manually.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the program as follows:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Simple App')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.text = None
        self.type = None
        self.input = None

        def OnInput(event):

            if self.text:
                self.text.Destroy()
                self.text = None
            if self.input:
                self.input.Destroy()
                self.input = None

            #static text
            self.text = wx.StaticText(panel, label ="Type your text", pos =(50, 100))

            #input text
            self.type = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (50, 150))

        def OnReadonly(event):

            if self.text:
                self.text.Destroy()
                self.text = None
            if self.type:
                self.type.Destroy()
                self.type = None

            #static text
            text = wx.StaticText(panel, label ="Status", pos =(50, 100))

            #input text
            self.input = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (50, 150), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
            self.input.SetValue("Waiting for your file")

        menu = wx.Menu()
        it = menu.Append(-1, "Input Text")
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        rt = menu.Append(-1, "Readonly Text")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnInput, it)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnReadonly, rt)
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(menu, "Simple Menu")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And I would probably merge the 'type' and 'input' variables into one variable